# How do I ensure that X-HTTP-Method headers are ignored?

Tags: asp.net, security, model-view-controller, x-http-method-override

I'm currently applying security fixes for a vulnerability which was found by a third party software. [This is the issue (Often Misused: HTTP Method Override vulnerability)](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/02-Configuration_and_Deployment_Management_Testing/06-Test_HTTP_Methods).

The request from the software was similar to:

```
POST /Home/ViewProfile HTTP/1.1
Referer: https://somesite.com/Home/ViewProfile?qrystr=blahblah
[...]
X-HTTP-METHOD: PUT
X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT
X-METHOD-OVERRIDE: PUT
[...]
```

And the response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]
```

The web application is not a RESTful API, it's just a an ASP.NET MVC site which only has GET and POST actions.

I have a few questions:

1. Is this a false positive given the type of app?
2. By default, does ASP.NET do anything with these headers X-HTTP-Method, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-METHOD-OVERRIDE if not explicitly told to do so such as in [this example?](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/http-put-or-delete-not-allowed-use-xhttpmethodoverride-for-your-rest-service-with-aspnet-web-api)
3. Regarding the first linked issue above, what is the best way to go about achieving the recommended remediations if they're necessary/applicable based on my case:

   "Ensure that only the required headers are allowed, and that the allowed headers are properly configured."

   and

   "Ensure that no workarounds are implemented to bypass security measures implemented by user-agents, frameworks, or web servers."

Another thing to note is I don't have access to modify IIS settings, but I can modify the Web.Config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with a scan from my security team. What I did was limiting the size of those requests to zero (0) in the web.config.  The server then returns a "HTTP Error 431.0 - Request Header Fields Too Large",  effectively blocking the overrides.

```
 </system.webServer>
    ...
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits>
          <headerLimits>
            <add header="X-Http-Method-Override" sizeLimit="0" />
            <add header="X-Method-Override" sizeLimit="0" />
            <add header="X-HTTP-Method" sizeLimit="0" />
          </headerLimits>
        </requestLimits>
        ...
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
   ...
  </system.webServer>
```

However, I haven't checked yet if this effectively cancels the alert by the security scanner. I suspect it might still show, but I'm ready to report back as a false positive because the server is blocking all calls with those headers. I'll let you know as soon as I get a response from the security team.

Comment: I just got a scan result from my team as well.  I couldn't find much online, except for this answer.  Thanks.